# How to set refs in React useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I'm trying to play a gsap animation on component did mount in a Gatsby site but my refs aren't being applied.

```js
const PricingList = ({ classes }) => {
    let pricingCard = useRef([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('start Animation', pricingCard.current);
        TweenMax.staggerFrom(pricingCard.current, 0.4, { opacity: 0, y: 100 }, 0.5);
    }, []);

    return (
        <StaticQuery
            query={graphql`
                {
                    Prices: contentfulConfig {
                        pricing {
                            priceBand {
                                title
                                price
                            }
                            priceBand2 {
                                price
                                title
                            }
                            priceBand3 {
                                price
                                title
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            `}
            render={(data) => (
                <Fragment>
                    <div className={classes.Container}>
                        <PricingItem
                            ref={(el) => {
                                pricingCard.current[0] = el;
                            }}
                        />
                        <PricingItem
                            ref={(el) => {
                                pricingCard.current[1] = el;
                            }}
                        />
                        <PricingItem
                            ref={(el) => {
                                pricingCard.current[2] = el;
                            }}
                        />
                    </div>
                </Fragment>
            )}
        />
    );
};
```

I have tried -

```js
pricingCard.current.push(el);
```

without any luck, I just get an empty array in console.

I have also tried -

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('start Animation', pricingCard.current);
        TweenMax.staggerFrom(pricingCard.current, 0.4, { opacity: 0, y: 100 }, 0.5);
    }, [pricingCard]);
```

Thinking it might need to wait to be updated after the component mounted, but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For animation you might want to use `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect`.

Is it going to be always 3 `PricingItem`s? In this case you can create 3 separate refs for each (`const pricingItem1 = useRef(null)`) and in render `<PricingItem ref={pricingItem1} />`.

Also can you confirm that the function from the render prop has been called?

Comment: Oh the function in the render prop isn't getting called. Nice catch. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: has your page made a call to the graphql endpoint and received response?

Comment: Yeah everything displays fine, its just the refs that seem to be the issue.

Comment: Hmm how about if you use `useStaticQuery` hook instead of using `StaticQuery` component?

Comment: Oh your useEffect hook is only called on initial mount (because it has empty array as dependencies list). It's not being called after graphql returned data. But render prop is called only after receiving data from graphql. You need to add something to the list of dependencies of useEffect which change after receiving data from graphql.

Comment: I think it would make sense to extract what you have in render prop into separate component and have `useEffect` for animation over there.